# passing argument to jython used in wsadmin.sh dynamically

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I need a help in wsadmin.sh scripting along with jython.
I am creating a script to provide console access to the users via wsadmin.sh
I am able to make it work if I hardcode the user name details inside the consoleacces.py file but My requirement is to give the user name details at run-time so that i can use the script for multiple times for different user.

**Working :**

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython  -f /tmp/consoleaccess.py
```

**content of consoleaccess.py**

```
AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole('[-accessids [user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/employeenumber=123,ou=people,ou=country,o=office] -roleName administrator -userids user1]')
AdminConfig.save()
agBean=AdminControl.queryNames('type=AuthorizationGroupManager,process=dmgr,*');null=AdminControl.invoke(agBean, 'refreshAll')
```

**Not working**

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /tmp/consoleaccess.py 123 user1 administrator
```

**content of consoleaccess.py**

```
 import sys
    AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole('[-accessids [user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/employeenumber=sys.argv[1],ou=people,ou=americas,o=SIAM_ED] -roleName sys.argv[3] -userids sys.argv[2]]')
    AdminConfig.save()
    agBean=AdminControl.queryNames('type=AuthorizationGroupManager,process=dmgr,*');null=AdminControl.invoke(agBean, 'refreshAll')
```

**Error :**

```
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node host1 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
WASX7303I: The following options are passed to the scripting environment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable: "[123, user1, administrator]"
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/tmp/consoleaccess.py"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX8009E: Invalid parameter: [-accessids [user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/employeenumber=sys.argv[1],ou=people,ou=americas,o=SIAM_ED] -roleName sys.argv[3] -userids sys.argv[2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the script as below.

**Note** : In wsadmin Jython, the name of the program, or script, is not part of sys.argv. So your first argument is *sys.argv[0]* and not *sys.argv[1]*

```
import sys

userEmpNo=sys.argv[0]
userName=sys.argv[1]
userRole=sys.argv[2]

AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole('[-accessids [user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/employeenumber=' +userEmpNo+ ',ou=people,ou=americas,o=SIAM_ED] -roleName ' +userRole+ ' -userids ' +userName+ ']')
AdminConfig.save()
agBean=AdminControl.queryNames('type=AuthorizationGroupManager,process=dmgr,*');null=AdminControl.invoke(agBean, 'refreshAll')
```

and run the script as

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /tmp/consoleaccess.py 123 user1 administrator
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the wsadmin jython and your updated script. That made the trick and now its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `--` to separate the flags from the arguments?

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /tmp/consoleaccess.py --  123 user1 administrator
```

and moving the sys.argv out of the string:

```
'...employeenumber=' + sys.argv[1] + ',ou=people,ou=americas,o=SIAM_ED] -roleName ' + sys.argv[3] + ' -userids ' + sys.argv[2]])
```

Comment: Oh, I see now you try to use sys.argv within the quoted parameter, it won't be resolved there.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer.. It looks like we need to move sys.argv out of the string to make it work.